# Why does Valgrind return executable file's exit code?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I want to run Valgrind in cp Linux command and watch the XML result of Valgrind.

when I run the below command to get XML output, the exit code is 1. because Valgrind runs the cp command.

```
valgrind --xml=yes --leak-check=full --verbose --track-origins=no --xml-file=/home/user/Desktop/test/cp_valgrind.xml --log-file=/home/user/Desktop/test/cp_valgrind.txt --error-exitcode=100 /home/user/Desktop/test/cp
```

I got the below error:

```
/home/user/Desktop/test/cp: missing file operand
Try '/home/user/Desktop/test/cp --help' for more information.
```

Why does Valgrind return the executable file's exit code?
How can I run Valgrind on an executable file without Valgrind runs it?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the point of valgrind to run an executable while monitoring it for bugs?

Comment: valgrind isn't a static analyzer. It doesn't look at the executable, it looks at the execution.

Comment: valgrind has a flag  --error-exitcode that says what if exit code if the executable file has Valgrind errors. so imagine we have an automated tool to say us what are executable files have Valgrind errors. but when runs Valgrind on the cp command the exit code is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind will return the guest return value by default.

If you specify `--error-exitcode` then it will return that value if there is an error from the view of the Valgrind tool *and* the guest returns 0. It will still return the guest return value of the Valgrind tool detects no errors. It does not translate a guest error code into the value specified by `--error-exitcode`, or override a non-zero guest error code.

In the table below `invalid_free` is a small testcase that generates a single memcheck error but returns 0.

|  | No mem error, no guest error | No mem error, guest error | Mem error, no guest error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Standalone | pwd ; echo $? -> 0 | cp ; echo $? -> 1 | invalid_free ; echo $? -> 0 |
| Under memcheck | valgrind -q pwd ; echo $? -> 0 | valgrind -q cp ; echo $? -> 1 | valgrind -q invalid_free ; echo $? -> 0 |
| Under memcheck with --error-code | valgrind -q --error-exitcode=42 pwd ; echo $? -> 0 | valgrind -q --error-exitcode=42 cp ; echo $? -> 1 | valgrind -q --error-exitcode=42 invalid_free ; echo $? -> **42** |

and a 4th column that I can't fit without scrolling

|  | Mem error, guest error |
| --- | --- |
| Standalone | invalid_free2 ; echo $? -> 1 |
| Under memcheck | valgrind -q invalid_free2 ; echo $? -> 1 |
| Under memcheck with --error-code | valgrind -q --error-exitcode=42 invalid_free2 ; echo $? -> **1** |